# I have an array a=[1,2,3,4,5,6] and in next line i want array that has only even values in it. Trying to do this by .collect but value is in boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
w=a.collect{|i| i%2==0}
p w
```

The result is coming to be

```
[false,true,false,true]
```

why?

When i am doing

```
w=a.collect{|i| i+2}
```

Result is an array like

```
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

Why? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to double check your results. For the given input, the first example would result in an array of 8 boolean values, not just 4. The latter example would also have 8 elements, not 9.

Comment: You're right sir. I have typed them myself. Should've copied them..will try to be exact next time.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `map` / `collect` (they are aliases), you need

```
array.select(&:even?)
```

or

```
array.reject(&:odd?)
```

These methods filter original array, unlike `map` that performs actions with every element and returns new array of the same length

That's why you get boolean array same length instead of filtering

Please read more in docs:

[`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map), [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-select), [`Array#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-reject)

Comment: See also `Enumerable#filter`.